# randomize Background image in an array for a button for AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, button, flash, random

I have a sample code:

```
backgroundChange_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomBG);
function randomBG(e: MouseEvent): void {
    var Background = new Array();
    Background[1] = "Ocean Floor.jpg";
    Background[2] = "Underwater Ruins.jpg";
    Background[3] = "Underwater Temple.jpg";
    Background[4] = "Background 1.jpg";
    Background[5] = "Background 2.jpg";
    Background[6] = "Background 3.jpg";
    Background[7] = "Background 4.jpg";
    Background[8] = "Background 5.jpg";
```

Does anyone know how to randomize the background images from an array by clicking a button?

Now: I have these changes...

I am not using the Array anymore, I am now using a MovieClip called `game_BG`, each frame were all bitmaps and then nothing happens when I clicked the button.

```
backgroundChange_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomBG);

function randomBG(e: MouseEvent = null): void 
{
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Background.length-1);
    if (rnd == 0) {
        game_BG.gotoAndStop(rnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: To start it's good practice to use the `Vector` class whenever applicable: [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html).

Also do you have these images loaded into your program already? You can either use a `Loader` or embed them directly. If so you can add them to the button container and set a random one to visible when needed.

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: A code example for what? Randomizing the background image or loading images onto your program? Because your post is about the background image randomizer so I assume you have the images loaded already.

Comment: yes, I have them in the library.

Comment: **(1)** _"How to randomize the background images from an array"_ is not making sense... Your code shows an Array so maybe you want to randomize (change) the array structure itself? Like do you want `"Ocean Floor.jpg"` to go from `[1]` to a random position like `[5]`? Or maybe you just want to get a random number for then using to pick an image from the array? **(2)** _"Yes, I have them in the library."_ Not enough useful info... In the library do they each have an **instance name**? I mean how is your code getting any picture from the Library? _eg:_ If `rnd == 4` then what's next in your code?

Comment: **PS**: After doing `if (rnd == 0) { rnd = 1; }` if you add `trace( "random image : " + Background[ rnd ]);` does the compiler tell you a random name from the array each time you test your function? If yes, is that enough? Or else explain what more is needed like _"The function must give back the random number so I can re-use it in a different function that adds some Library image to Stage"_...

Comment: When the button is clicked, it changed the different background

Comment: The message says "random image : undefined"

Comment: Try: `trace( "random num is : " + rnd );` then followed by `trace( "random image : " + Background[ rnd ]);` ... If it says undefined then check if `rnd` is a number between 1 and 8. If not, then you need to fix your randomization code.

Comment: I tested earlier and it says "random image : undefined"

Comment: Why do you think it says "undefined"? Is it because your `rnd` number is  not in range of the array size? Or maybe your Array itself is invalid... That's why I updated to tell you to check **both** the value of `rnd` before also checking which array item (background) your `rnd` will get.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting **undefined** then...

- Either your `rnd` is wrong (it points to a not-existing position of Array).
- Or else the Array itself is not a valid object (so create it properly).
- Finally (in AS3) you must add **data types** when declaring your variables.

See if this example helps you get a random number.

```
var rnd :uint = 0;
var BG :Button = new Button();
var Background :Array = new Array(9);

Background[0] = "empty";
Background[1] = "Ocean Floor.jpg";
Background[2] = "Underwater Ruins.jpg";
Background[3] = "Underwater Temple.jpg";
Background[4] = "Background 1.jpg";
Background[5] = "Background 2.jpg";
Background[6] = "Background 3.jpg";
Background[7] = "Background 4.jpg";
Background[8] = "Background 5.jpg";
    
backgroundChange_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomBG);


function randomBG(e: MouseEvent = null): void 
{
    //# length is 9 so "minus 1" to get val between 0 to 8
    rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * (Background.length-1) );
    
    //# if zero then re-run the function for a new random
    if (rnd == 0) { randomBG(); }
    
    //# check the results...
    trace( "Background is : " + Background ); //is Array?
    trace( "random num is : " + rnd ); //is between 1 and 8?
    trace( "random image  : " + Background[ rnd ]); //is JPG file name?
    
}
```

Comment: OK. The codes are good, then if I clicked the button, will the background image will change?

Comment: _"Will the background image will change?"_ I'm not sure **what is background image**. You need a container on the Stage to hold image. Either load an image into **Sprite** (is one frame) or put (drag) all images in frames of a **MovieClip** (is multiple frames). **Options**: **(1)** If you have an images MC on Stage then you can just control the MC with `gotoAndStop` to get to the frame that has the required image. **(2)** Another way is to load by code the image from Library. See `Step 2` and onwards of [this tutorial](https://www.atksolutions.com/articles/flash_as3_load_display_sprite.html).

Comment: I have an image as a bitmap or a Movieclip.

Comment: I am not understanding... Do you have a question? If yes, also mention what you did so far, then I can understand better.

Comment: I have the code filled, what about an images MC on Stage? How would I set to change it when I clicked the button?

Comment: Did you give the _"images MC on Stage"_ an **instance** name? Use that name to access the Stage object. Tell the MC to go to another frame to change picture (that is, if you put your images on different frames of MC)

Comment: I named it, "game_BG"

Comment: _"I named it, `game_BG`"_ Okay so what is the problem? You don't tell anything about this `game_BG` so now I don't know if you already have put images on different frames of the MC, or maybe the problem is that  first you need to load image from Library to put into the MC. Read again my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529520/randomize-background-image-in-an-array-for-a-button-for-as3/71734804?noredirect=1#comment126863412_71734804) from **2 weeks ago**.  It gives you two options, choose MClip version or choose Sprite version. Putting images into MClip is easiest way.

Comment: PS: I did not want to say this but it is not normal to struggle for 3 weeks just show an image.  This is a basic 1 hour lesson for beginners. So try this... **(1)** In Flash IDE, put `game_BG` on the Stage. **(2)** Double-click the MC to enter its timeline. At frame 1 of the MC, just drag image from Library into Stage (now image is on frame 1 of MC). Add another frame on timeline and drag next image. Repeat this process of `add frame then drag image into Stage at that frame point`. Finally your MC has multiple frames, each one with image. Change image by code _eg:_ `game_BG.gotoAndStop(3);`

Comment: function randomBG(e: MouseEvent = null): void {
 rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Background.length);
 if (rnd == 0) {
  //randomBG();
  game_BG.gotoAndStop(randomBG);
 }

Comment: **(1)** Replace `* Background.length` with this `* (Background.length-1)` **(2)** Did you put images in each frame of **game_BG** (put means drag from Library into Stage at each frame of the MC)?

Comment: yes. I have put them in each frame

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask... Is everything working now or is there still an error / problem? You can use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71529520/edit) to update your Question with new details about what you did (put images in each frame of game_BG) and/or what is not working (after you click the button to run `function randomBG`)...

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label function Function() {} not found in scene function Function() {}.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
 at BlowfishPong_fla::MainTimeline/randomBG()[BlowfishPong_fla.MainTimeline::frame28:247]

Comment: It's telling you that `randomBG` is a **function**, it is not some frame named "randomBG" inside the "game_BG" Movieclip... What are you trying to do? If you want to to use `rnd` (is a random number) then try as : `game_BG.gotoAndStop( rnd );` ...

Comment: The code was already changed. Inside the game_BG, each frame were all bitmaps and then nothing happens when I clicked the button.

Comment: **(1)** Change the _"**Now:**"_ part [of your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71529520/edit) to show the code you are using now... Because I don't know what _"The code was already changed"_ means **exactly**... Because I can't see your screen..... **(2)** Do you have **game_BG** on the Stage? It should work

Comment: OK. You have `game_BG.gotoAndStop(rnd);` inside an `IF` statement... remove the `IF` part and just first set your `rnd = ...` then got to the `rnd` number frame in your movieclip as `game_BG.gotoAndStop(rnd);` ... You only need the `IF` part if using the Array (because you wrote it to start as `array[1] =` but all arrays start at `[0]` so the IF statement would make the function run again to try find a not `0` number)

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var rnd:uint = 0;
var BG: Button = new Button();
var Background: Array = new Array(9);
Background[0] = "Ocean Floor.jpg";
Background[1] = "Underwater Ruins.jpg";
Background[2] = "Underwater Temple.jpg";
Background[3] = "Background 5.jpg";
Background[4] = "Background 2.jpg";
Background[5] = "Background 3.jpg";
Background[6] = "Background 4.jpg";
Background[7] = "Background 9.jpg";
Background[8] = "Background 10.jpg";

backgroundChange_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomBG);
function randomBG(e: MouseEvent = null): void {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Background.length-1);
    game_BG.gotoAndStop(rnd);

    //trace( "Background is : " + Background ); //is Array?
    //trace( "random num is : " + rnd ); //is between 1 and 8?
    //trace( "random image  : " + Background[ rnd ]); //is JPG file name?
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).